# Laravel Ajax Request $request empty result

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have an ajax request method post like this on the view :

```
$.ajax({
                data: { test : 1337, _token: "{{csrf_token()}}" },
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{ route("get_image_by_parent_id") }}',
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log(res)
                },
            });
```

and here is my route code :

```
Route::post('backend/blog/get_image_by_parent_id', 'Backend\BlogController@get_image_by_parent_id')->name('get_image_by_parent_id');
```

here is my controller :

```
public function get_image_by_parent_id(Request $request)
    {
        echo json_encode($request);
    }
```

when i look in network tab it's show me like this :

[Network tab debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb4aY.png)

Anyone can help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo json_encode($request);
```

This is *not* correct because the request object does not hold your request data directly to it. It is a collection of many other things in the variable-

If you want to access all your **requests** then I suggest you do this instead-

```
$request->all();
```

You can use **dump()** or **dd()** as per your requirement to print the output on console.

```
dump($request->all());
```

Comment: oooh ... i got it know ... i thought when i do dump $request it's like dump $_POST ... Thank you mate !